# Controling WebView Elements Not Working

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I've looked at a few SO posts regarding this issue, and below is what I have came up with:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String password = "a123345";
        //webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = '" + "hi" + "';");
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:var uselessvar  = document.getElementByName('q').value='" + password + "';");
        Log.d("d","Done");

    }
}
```

But nothing I have tried has worked. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things about this

- Try to avoid using Thread.sleep in main thread
- Dont load script with constant time
- You can use of callback like `WebViewClient` callbacks which have at least `onPageFinished` method which you can use to load the JS
- Add `setJavaScriptEnabled` to run the JS

Example :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
                                String failingUrl) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        String password = "a123345";
       view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
               "document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value = '" + password + "'; " +
               "})()");
    }
});
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

Comment: thanks, it works but this `view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByName('Log In')[0].click(); " +
                        "})()");` does not work. I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined" any idea why?

Comment: Which page are you using this js..? are you sure on that page you have "Log In" name..?